# VBA Outlook Incoming Items class

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote a code using `Items_add` event to manage incoming mailitems.
I recently found out that recall messages and auto-replies (out of office) are not mailitems because my code won`t process them.

I tried googling it but could not find an answer.

So, how can I get incoming recall items and auto-replies that arrive in the inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just check what it is? Select the item in your inbox and then run a short bit of code such as below and it will come back and tell you its a report item for recall messages.

```
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

MsgBox TypeName(objSelection.Item(1))
Set objSelection = Nothing
```

Comment: Or you can use OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click the Item button and it will show the live object with all its properties, methods, and events.